# TypeError: i is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use the jquery.validate function for real time validation, but for some reason I am getting an error in the Firebug console and nothing happens.

```
TypeError: i is undefined

...,s="on"+e.type.replace(/^validate/,"");i.settings[s]&&i.settings[s].call(i,this[... (jquery.validate.min.js)
```

Here's the code:

```
        $('.form-group').validate({
            rules: {
                field: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                field2: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                field3: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            }
        });
```

Here's the form:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                        <label class="text-right col-xs-2 control-label"> Field</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
                                <input name="field">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <label class="text-right col-xs-2 control-label"> Field2</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
                                <input name="field2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <label class="text-right col-xs-2 control-label"> Field3</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
                            <input name="field3">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

I am not sure why it's not working. Is there a work around? I use it in other places without any problem, so I am assuming there's a way to fix this particular error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot attach the `.validate()` method to a `div`.   It can only be attached to a `<form>`.

Comment: can I use an id selector?

Comment: Seems to have fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @henry, you can use any valid jQuery selector.